# Is it possible to edit or delete previous experience details on LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin

Is it possible to edit or delete previous experience details on your LinkedIn profile?

I had a look at their [help page](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1646/kw/edit%20previous%20position/session/L3RpbWUvMTMxNTQxNjgzMy9zaWQvWThvMUl2RGs%3D) but the method mentioned there seems to be applicable only for the experience listed under "Current", not the past.

> To remove a position:
>
> - Click Profile at the top of your home page.
> - Scroll down to the Experience section and find the position.
> - Click Edit.
> - Click the Remove this position link under Update.

On my profile:

[image: linkedin profile]

So, is there a way to edit the previous experience details(paid account feature?) or is it not possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to keep scrolling down the page. You don't need a paid account.

From the toolbar:

> Profile > [Edit Profile](http://www.linkedin.com/profile/edit)

After the grey box summary, there will be all your profile sections, Experience, Languages, Skills, etc.

> [image: where to edit previous experience]

Each of your previous positions will have **Edit** next to them.

Click that and then you'll be taken to a page to edit just that node.

On that page you will see **Remove this position** under the Update button.

Comment: Perfect. I seemed to have ignored the experience section.